# .json not showing in Safari, jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, https, safari

I created a jQuery plugin that shows up in Chrome as expected, but in Safari, it is not loading the following URL so the badges are showing up: https://www.codeschool.com/users/audreyklammer.json

I think this is the issue. Any ideas on either what I should console.log or does anything stand out? I will do the work just would love your input.

Here is the full code on my GitHub but also pasted below: 
https://github.com/Klammertime/Badge-Widget/blob/master/dist/js/jquery.insignia.js

```
    ;(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var insigniaList = $('.insignia');
        for(var i = 0; i < insigniaList.length; i++){
            var insigniaEntry = insigniaList[i];
            console.log(insigniaEntry);
            $(insigniaEntry).insignia(insigniaEntry.dataset.treehouse, insigniaEntry.dataset.codeschool);  
        }     
    });

    $.fn.insignia = function(usernameTreehouse, usernameCodeschool) {
        this.empty();
        if (usernameTreehouse) {
            getBadges(usernameTreehouse, this);
        }
        if (usernameCodeschool) {
            getBadges2(usernameCodeschool, this);
        }
    }

    function getBadges(usernameTreehouse, element) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://teamtreehouse.com/" + usernameTreehouse + ".json",
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(dataBack) {
                var badges = dataBack.badges;
                $(element).append("<h3>I have taken " + badges.length + " lessons and scored " + dataBack.points.total +
                    " points at Treehouse!</h3><div class=\"badges\"></div>");
                badges.forEach(function(badge, i) {
                    if (i < 7) {
                        element.find(".badges").append("<li class=\"badgeImages\"> <img src=' " + badge.icon_url + " '/></li>");
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(dataBack) {
                console.log("something went wrong.");
                //this happen when call fails
            }
        });
    }

    function getBadges2(usernameCodeschool, element) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.codeschool.com/users/" + usernameCodeschool + ".json",
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            async: true,
            success: function(dataBack) {
                console.log(dataBack);
                $(element).append("<h3>I have taken " + dataBack.badges.length + " lessons and scored " + dataBack.user.total_score +
                    " points at Codeschool!</h3><div class=\"badges2\"></div>");
                var badge = dataBack.badges;
                console.log(badge);
                badge.forEach(function(badge, i) {
                    if (i < 7) {
                        element.find(".badges2").append("<li class=\"badgeImages\"> <img src=' " + badge.badge + " '/></li>");
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(dataBack) {
                console.log("something went wrong.");
                //this happen when call fails
            }
        });
    }

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: It looks like you have to be logged in for the JSON endpoint to return anything, are you logged in to codeschool/teamtreehouse in Safari? I would check the network tab, it will show you what's happening with the AJAX requests

Comment: I'm not logged in to either. Maybe it's the https on codeschool and Safari's tighter security settings therefore have to be logged in? Its showing that its failing to retrieve that data.

Comment: Someone suggested sending authentication headers with my request.